# why is my IOS app title (under icon) not appearing localized?

Tags: ios, iphone, coronasdk, cfbundledisplayname

I'm using Corona SDK but was hoping for some advice here, as I'm hoping someone can spot my error.  I am trying to get the app title that appears under the icon localized.

I'm doing the following (in Corona SDK) this but I'm still not seeing the app title change under the icon when I change the "LANGUAGE" setting of my iPhone.

a) put CFBundleLocalizations in build.settings per below

```
settings = {
    iphone =
    {
        plist =
        {
             CFBundleIconFile = "Icon.png",
             CFBundleIconFiles = { << cut for this put >>},
             CFBundleLocalizations = {
                "English",
                "French",
                "Japanese",
                "Chinese",
            },
        },
    },
```

b) put a 'InfoPlist.strings' file for each language in a directory like 'fr.lproj' under the root.  In the strings file put:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = “Parachutiste”;
```

QUESTION: Any advice or do you spot an error in what I'm doing. I must be either (a) missing something here or (b) misunderstanding how to test a change of language on my iPhone to test this?   (i.e. I'm currently assuming I just change the language of the phone and this should trigger a different app title to appear under the icon)